# How can I stop accumulated Google Chrome background processes?

Tags: google-chrome, process, task-management

Sometimes invisible instances of Google Chrome accumulate and prevent me from starting the browser:

```
$ ps -ef | grep chrome
ak        4044     1  4 11:30 ?        00:00:01 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4047  4044  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4049     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
ak        4139  4044  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/3.0.7_0/plugin/screen_capture_64.so --lang=en-US --plugin-data-dir=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default --channel=4044.0x618d838.1464152706 --enable-crash-reporter=D8EC5832E6B1783FEA1F118FC4B1AAE0,Ubuntu 10.10
ak        4150     1  3 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4153  4150  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4155     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
ak        4244  4150  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/3.0.7_0/plugin/screen_capture_64.so --lang=en-US --plugin-data-dir=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default --channel=4150.0x48c1e38.1952918361 --enable-crash-reporter=D8EC5832E6B1783FEA1F118FC4B1AAE0,Ubuntu 10.10
ak        4253     1  6 11:30 ?        00:00:01 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4256  4253  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4258     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
ak        4348  4253  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/3.0.7_0/plugin/screen_capture_64.so --lang=en-US --plugin-data-dir=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default --channel=4253.0x598ca38.734301885 --enable-crash-reporter=D8EC5832E6B1783FEA1F118FC4B1AAE0,Ubuntu 10.10
ak        4355     1  4 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4358  4355  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4360     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
ak        4449  4355  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/3.0.7_0/plugin/screen_capture_64.so --lang=en-US --plugin-data-dir=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default --channel=4355.0x4bb6e38.554350998 --enable-crash-reporter=D8EC5832E6B1783FEA1F118FC4B1AAE0,Ubuntu 10.10
ak        4457     1  5 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4460  4457  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4462     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
ak        4553  4457  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/3.0.7_0/plugin/screen_capture_64.so --lang=en-US --plugin-data-dir=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default --channel=4457.0x5338c38.1605325542 --enable-crash-reporter=D8EC5832E6B1783FEA1F118FC4B1AAE0,Ubuntu 10.10
ak        4559     1  8 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4562  4559  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ak        4564     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote
ak        4653  4559  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=plugin --plugin-path=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/3.0.7_0/plugin/screen_capture_64.so --lang=en-US --plugin-data-dir=/home/ak/.config/google-chrome/Default --channel=4559.0x60e6638.1319164624 --enable-crash-reporter=D8EC5832E6B1783FEA1F118FC4B1AAE0,Ubuntu 10.10
ak        4661  4020  0 11:30 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto chrome
```

If I try to start Chrome while these are present, the following error message is displayed:

> Your profile could not be opened
>   correctly.
>
> Some features may be unavailable. 
>   Please check that the profile exists
>   and you have permission to read and
>   write its contents.

Short of logging out of Ubuntu, how can I get rid of these to allow Chrome to start again? My first guess didn't work as I expected:

```
$ killall google-chrome
google-chrome: no process found
```

Running `kill` on each process two times in a row gets the job done:

```
$ kill 4044 4047 4049 4139 4150 4153 4155 4244 4253 4256 4258 4348 4355 4358 4360 4449 4457 4460 4462 4553 4559 4562 4564 4653
$ !!
kill 4044 4047 4049 4139 4150 4153 4155 4244 4253 4256 4258 4348 4355 4358 4360 4449 4457 4460 4462 4553 4559 4562 4564 4653
bash: kill: (4139) - No such process
bash: kill: (4244) - No such process
bash: kill: (4348) - No such process
bash: kill: (4449) - No such process
bash: kill: (4553) - No such process
bash: kill: (4653) - No such process
```

but I would love to have a less cumbersome solution.

Comment: You don't have to kill the processes twice. According to your output, the processes don't exist when you execute the command a second time.

Comment: @George The six listed processes don't exist, but the rest are still present after the first kill command.

Comment: Sorry, never mind then.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A grab-bag of chrome poisons:

`pgrep chrome | xargs kill`  # this is basically "pkill chrome"

Same thing, but sleep for 1/3 of a second in between:

```
for i in `pgrep chrome` ; do kill $i ;  sleep .33 ; done
```

Keep on killing 'til the killing's done :

```
while pgrep chrome ; do pkill chrome ; done
```

Short and sweet (but won't exit until you exit manually) :

```
watch pkill chrome
```

Might work? :

```
for i in `pgrep chrome` ; do kill $i && wait $i ;  sleep .33 ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to see “Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly. To repoen ...”, then it is important to signal only the root of the chrome process tree, like so:

```
pkill --oldest chrome
```

See [full explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174451/85669).

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
kill $(ps -C google-chrome -o pid=)
```

Comment: This [did not kill](http://paste.ubuntu.com/575127/) any processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
pkill chrome
```

Seems like I need 5 extra characters...

Comment: I had to run this [three times in a row](http://paste.ubuntu.com/575124/) for it to work.

Comment: Have you tried to give it some more time?

Answer (score 1):

I think that not all of those are processes, but are rather threads.

You tried `killall -15 google-chrome chrome`?  That should kill all google-chrome processes and threads with a `SIGTERM` signal.  If that doesnt work, you can always try `killall -9 google-chrome chrome` (HIGHLY NOT ADVISED Unless you ABSOLUTELY need to kill the processes without them saving data)

Comment: I actually took the `kill -9` stuff out of my original, so I wouldn't be responsible for incidental breakage.  (That being said, I've used it plenty of times....)

Comment: Is there a difference between `killall` and `killall -15`?

Comment: killall without any arguments automatically uses signal 15 which is `SIGTERM`, however i'm always in the habit of specifying which code the system should use to send to the process(es)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo killall chrome
```

Then go into Settings, pick Advanced, and near the bottom you will find a switch where you can set it to NOT allow background processes to run when the program exits.