# 12.04: How to end all chrome related process after closing browser?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

Even after closing Google Chrome, there are many background processes running and consuming lot of memory. How do I end all the processes when I close Chrome? Following is a picture of processes after closing Chrome browser.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem plus chrome was putting an Icon on the menu bar.

Come to find out their is a setting in Chrome that appears to keep chrome in memory all the time.

Make chrome completely shut down.

Within chrome:

Settings:

Show advanced settings...

Unchecked "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"

I noticed the icon in the menu bar a couple of days ago must have happen during an update.

Mark

Answer (score 3):

`killall chrome` will do the needful.

Comment: That will leave other processes associated with Chrome but different names alive like those called `chrome-sandbox` in the process list in the question.

Comment: Since my answer was deleted somehow I'll move it here:  After you tell it to `killall chrome` you may want to restart the program then go into Settings, pick Advanced, and near the bottom you will find a switch where you can set it to NOT allow background processes to run when the program exits.  Uncheck that box and it will not happen again.

Answer (score 2):

That setting under Chrome config doesn't close the proccesses after closing Chrome. In fact that changed nothing.
I have the same problem here and I don't want to open a terminal window and running a line of code every time I close Chrome.
This is, in my opinion, a flaw of development.
There is another topic with the same discussion: [How can I stop accumulated Google Chrome background processes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27604/how-can-i-stop-accumulated-google-chrome-background-processes)

Comment: It works for me on my end, you may want to check if your system have any malware or even the antivirus software that is not allowing the option to kick in. It works perfectly as intended from my test on a windows 10 system 64bit. Have not test it on my ubuntu's machine tho.

Comment: No, there is no viruses nor malware and no antivirus either. It is very very very rare an Ubuntu machine to get some of those.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
pkill chrome
```

Or maybe this?

```
while pgrep chrome ; do pkill chrome ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Ubuntu 14.10 box, I found out that the last remaining process was chromium-browser --pinch-zoom enabled. After disabling this, the problem stopped for me. I had enabled this in regular Chrome for the touch screen support and I think it synced it somehow. Anyway, try that. I imagine this will work for regular Chrome as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Daswebmastri, Can you please explain how you disabled that option or where it is listed?